# Questions about the Wordpress Media Library

Tags: wordpress, media-library

I have two related questions regarding wordpress and media Library:

1. In Wordpress Media Library (version 3.5.1) There is the option to **associate an image with a post**. Does anyone know what changes does this do in the database. From what I found there are two tables that appear to be related to media library and posts association. The First is `wp_posts` table with three fields related: `post_type=attachment`, `post_mime_type=image`, `post_parent=<associated post id>`. Also `wp_postmeta` with fields `meta_key=_wp_attached_file` or `=_wp_attachment_metadata`.
   Are there any other tables/fields involved ? Is there an article describing these in detail?
   Now, programmaticaly speaking there seem to be two functions related to the above: `wp_insert_attachment` and `wp_update_attachment_metadata`. Are there any more or are they the only ones?
2. The `wp_insert_attachment` function needs an absolute filename. If the image is already on local server and we just have its (local) URL how can we find its absolute path programmatically? I am asking because the above function actually uploads a file which is not what I want since the file is already on the server.
   Alternatively, is there another function that takes just a local file URI and just associates it with a post without trying to upload it first?